# Print Array2 2D char array

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I am trying to print a 2D char array in SML which is in the form of:

```
val arr = Array2.fromList [[#"a", #"b", #"c"], [#"d", #"e", #"f"], [#"g", #"h", #"i"]];
```

Note that the last element in each row **is not** an `#"\n"` element.

The result must be in the following form, where every row is represented in a new line:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Is there any way to do this in SML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate and print a full row at a time by using [`Array2.row`, `Array2.nRows`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html) and [`CharVector.tabulate`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/mono-vector.html#SIG:MONO_VECTOR.tabulate:VAL):

```
Array2.row   : 'a array * int -> 'a Vector.vector
Array2.nRows : 'a array -> int
CharVector.tabulate : int * (int -> char) -> string
```

You could define a function `app_row` that takes an `Array2.array` and calls a function `f` on each row, extracted as a vector. And a function `vec_to_str` that takes that vector `vec` and converts it to a *string*; then print it.

```
fun app_row f arr =
    let fun loop i = if i = Array2.nRows arr then ()
                     else (f (Array2.row (arr, i)); loop (i+1))
    in loop 0 end

fun vec_to_str vec =
    CharVector.tabulate (Vector.length vec, fn i => Vector.sub (vec, i))

fun showMatrix arr =
    app_row (fn row => print (vec_to_str row ^ "\n")) arr
```

Trying this for size:

```
- showMatrix arr;
abc
def
ghi
> val it = () : unit
```

This solution should be less I/O intensive than e.g. using `Array2.appi` and print each letter one at a time. It's also slightly more complicated because it involves converting a "*char Vector.vector*" into a "*CharVector.vector*" (aka a *string*). (The difference between the two is subtle.)

Still, an alternative solution akin to the solution of P. Antoniadis, but where you don't need to specify the dimensions (since they can be extracted using e.g. `Array2.nCols` and `Array2.nRows`):

```
fun showMatrix arr =
    Array2.appi Array2.RowMajor (fn (_, col, c) =>
      print (str c ^ (if col + 1 = Array2.nCols arr then "\n" else "" )))
      {base=arr,row=0,col=0,nrows=NONE,ncols=NONE}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function as follows:

```
fun print_arr (arr,N,col) = ()
| print_arr(arr,row,M) = (print("\n");print_arr(arr,row+1,0))
| print_arr(arr,row,col) = (print(Array.sub(arr,row,col)); print_arr(arr,row,col+1))
```

Note that N,M are the number of rows and columns respectively. Here you print every element recursively. When you reach the end of a row, you print a new line and, then, you call the function with the next row as argument. Your initial arguments should be (arr,**0**,**0**).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the code has some issues.
#1: I am using the Array2 structure so I replaced `Array.sub` with `Array2.sub`
#2: Even with that change I get an error: 
`Error: match redundant
          (arr,N,col) => ...
    -->   (arr,row,M) => ...
    -->   (arr,row,col) => ...`
#3: The array is a char array not a sting array. So print won't work unless there is an easy way to convert to string.

Comment: You can convert a char to string by using Char.toString(). Have you defined N and M in your program?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works if I specify N and M, but the answer of Simon Shine is better. because it calculates N and M inside the function.